# How to see if domain is using Google Apps with Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps

Within my Python GAE application I need to know if a user's domain is a Google Apps domain. Until now I've been sending a request to https://www.google.com/a/domainName/ServiceLogin. If the response had "Sorry, you've reached a login page for a domain that isn't using Google Apps" included, the domain was not using Google Apps. However, recently I noticed that this method doesn't seem to work anymore. Do any alternative methods exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `email` in the list of scopes you request from the user. In the [response token](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth) there will be an `hd` parameter if it's a Google Apps account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems this is indeed what I was looking for. However, now I keep getting the "insufficient permission" error. I have included the following scopes:

     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. I cleared the local cache and it works fine. Thank you again!